# DDD Implementation detail using a Service

Tags: design-patterns, repository, domain-driven-design

I have two distinct repositories that I will be using simultaneously throughout my app.

There will be instances when I need to read from one (REST WS) and then turn around write to another (SQLite DB).

Should this be done in a "domain-service", or is ok to do within the presentation/application layer?

**NOTE:** To give some context, I have a separate service-process that fetches new records from a remote WS, and then makes them available to another process by writing to a local DB, which it then in turn loads from.

One process is a service that deals with fetching and updating data between the local and remote DB's. The other process is the actual app that operates solely off the local DB, and issues requests to the service-process via a request-queue table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably have one service for the REST reads, one for the SQLite writes, and one (a Facade) that binds them together.  The pattern here is the [Facade Pattern.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern)

Comment: Ok, that sounds do-able. Depending on the circumstances, I will be reading and writing from both repositories. Should I have 4 separate services, one for each operation (rep1-read, rep1-write, rep2-read, rep2-write) ? Or 2 services that do both read and write ?

Comment: Up to you, but I wouldn't go overboard.  ONe service per endpoint is usually enough...